# Android eclipse java changing map views

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mapview

I am creating a mobile app for location awareness.. i created a button, for when the button is clicked i want to switch between Satellite and Street views on the map. How would i go about doing this? I have created an if statement but it doesn't seem to work when i run it on the emulator. So i created a new class and changed the view. Is there any easier way of doing this as it still doesnt seem to display the new type of map view?

Answer (score 1):

changing view is not that difficult.
You must be having mapView. you can use

- mapView.setSatellite(true);
- mapView.setStreetView(true);

like wise as per your need. you can use single button to toggle between the two views.

Comment: @Harshad yes ive been tryin that.. in my initial gps.java file i have set it to satellite view.. but ive inserted a button so that when its clicked it is suppose to change to street view. is there a way of doing that?

Comment: initially you have set it to sreetView,then in onClickListener of your button say 'mapView.setSatellite(true);' if it is not appearing then include 'mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)'. If still it dint work paste some of your code.

Comment: private void initMapView() {
  map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map); 
  controller = map.getController();
  map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  map.setStreetView(true);
  
        Button btnChangeView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
        btnChangeView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         
             public void onClick(View v) {
              map.setSatellite(true);
              map.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
         });
 }

Comment: @Harshad have u any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @IrishGal. Actually it should work. Ok lets do it from beginning. atleast check if it is changing or not. do not press button. just try with both setStreetView and setSatelliteView one by one.and see if it is chaning. if it works there then on button click it should work. I have done the same and used one toggle button to switch between these two and it was like this only.

Comment: @Harshad for some reason it won't... Could it possibly be the emulator?? I cannot seem to get it to show StreetView now by putting in the line map.StreetView(true); before the button.

Comment: @IrishGal are you just able to see greed lines or map texture is visible??  I hope you have selected google API AVD for emulator. have Internet permission and have used <uses-library> com.google.androd.maps in your manifest.